# Set values of excluded values in Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a MVC5 ASP.NET application with Entity Framework 6 I have the following Create method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "folio,fecha,almacen,cliente,plaza,usuario,id_factura")] facturas_prueba facturas_prueba)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          db.facturas_prueba.Add(facturas_prueba);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     ViewBag.almacen = new SelectList(db.CATALMA, "COD_ALM", "NOM_ALM", facturas_prueba.almacen);
     ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.CATCTES, "COD_CTE", "NOM_CTE", facturas_prueba.cliente);
     ViewBag.usuario = new SelectList(db.FACPARU, "cod_usu", "cod_Alm", facturas_prueba.usuario);
     ViewBag.plaza = new SelectList(db.PLAZAS, "PLAZA", "LAST_COD_CTE", facturas_prueba.plaza);
     return View(facturas_prueba);
}
```

As you can see, by default is using a `[Bind(Include =` .As far I know, I could use to only include request parameters that I want. So, I just want folio, fecha, almacen and cliente. The others fields I would like to manually set them (for the moment, hardcoded values) and delete any field related to them in the view (because we don't users to put those values).
How is the MVC-way to this...?

Comment: I think you said it yourself, delete the fields from the view and set them manually in the controller. If you really want to get fancy, I suppose you could create a custom model binder to do the setting and inclusion/exclusion for you, but I think that might be overkill.

Comment: The current problem is that I don't how to set them manually in the controller. The binder sets those values directly to facturas_prueba object? :/

Comment: you can specify default values for any field in any table.. or you can just set the properties in the constructor

Comment: @Jakotheshadows I manually set the propeties of the facturas_prueba instance and worked. But, should I do this before or inside of `ModelState.IsValid` block?

Comment: I would do it before the ModelState.IsValid block- that way you're validating the manually set fields so you know that your hard coded values are valid.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows, No point setting them before `ModelState.IsValid`. `ModelState` errors are added during the binding process so its to late.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the MVC-way to this...?

Use a different model type for your view and your persistence layer.  Your "ViewModel" class would contain only the types/properties that are exposed in the view (or hidden but required for the view to function properly).

When the data is submitted for an add/update - the existing fields are retrieved from the source, merged with the submitted data, and then persisted back.